# React : A hierarchy of my component tree is too deeply nested - Is it OK?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and developing an app with react + some libraries like react router and redux.

When I inspected my app with React Development Tools, I found that too many components are nested in the component tree(components in components in components..)

Worse, since I'm using libraries like react-router, it seems inevitable that some HOCs from those libraries(such as 'withRouter') are added in the tree.

Is it okay, or should I change the structure so that components are not that nested?

For me, as a beginner, it looks like that too deeply nested components could be problematic.

Comment: Any suitably complex React app will have deeply-nested components; that is the nature of a web page. Whether or not it's "too" deep is a matter of opinion and the requirements of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally OK for your components to be deeply nested.

It just depends on what you want.